# Turning string with line jumps into li in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object property (string) coming from the database with line jumps, looking like this:

[image]

Right now, when I display it in the frontend it just shows like this:

```
1223123 2121 3223 54545 1221 1221
```

What I need is this:

```
<ul>
 <li>1223123</li>
 <li>2121</li>
 ...
</ul>
```

Is there any way to turn such string into a li using a filter? I thought about string replace, but I assume it wouldn't work.

Comment: use split to change this to array, then you can make a ng-repeat with it to build the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="artist in artsts.split('\r')"> {{artist}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It spits out one list element containing the full string (not split) : /

Comment: Try splitting on '\n' and '\r\n' also.